# Programming for math

Tags: excel, programming-languages, vba

I have a project with a certain function, `f(x)=Sin(x)`. My code will prompt the user to enter upper and lower limits of `x`, and the number of intervals it will have `n`. The code will then assign the fixed values of `x` into one column and the values of `f(x)` in the other column. Then, it should create a graph of the function. So far, I have

```
Function y() 'function 1 on sheet 1'
    Dim a As Double
    Dim b As Double
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim X As Integer
    a = InputBox("Enter your value for a on the interval [a,b]")
    b = InputBox("Enter your value for b on the interval [a,b]")
    n = InputBox("Enter the number of intervals for the function")

    If (b <= a) Then
        b = InputBox("Enter a value for b that is greater than the value you entered for a")
    End If

    Do While (x >= a) Or (x <= b)
        y = Sin(x)
    Loop
End Function
```

What I am having trouble with is creating the columns. I don't know how to make the code return the fixed values into one column and the variable values in the other column. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You might want to take a look at your formatting and add some information about the programming language / perhaps a tag.

Comment: First, when you check for `b<=a`, in the inputBox you should write - "Enter a value for b that is more than the value you entered for a". Not less as you have now. Second, why do you need x, when you have the a, b and the interval. Just start from a, a+interval, .... and so on until it is more than b.

Comment: Sounds like your only problem is not with the math itself but with learning how to send information to the spreadsheet

Comment: Also,if you ever execute the `y = Sin(x)`, it's an infinite loop, since `x` never changes...

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose of this function should be. Is it for educational purpose only? Or is it a homework with a specific exercise? Because this can easily be done without the use of VBA with just formulas. As a hint: Instead of the `Do` loop you might have a look at the [`For … Next … Step` Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251601.aspx) if `n` can only be integer.